# Running mono app in background streamwriter not writing to textfile

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Im running my mono C# application in ubuntu as a daemon using upstart.
App uses streamwriter and has suppose to write to logfile,
while this works if I run my application in foreground, but when I run
it in background it doesn't write to file.
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found out from the logs that if you run application in background and if your application uses paths from root directory, you must specify the full path.

Like for example -
instead of path from apps root directory you must provide full path to the source like in this case here "/usr/share/myapp/res/pic.jpg" **instead of** "res/pic.jpg"

Comment: Well.. That's because / denotes the root directory. You should use the relative path `./res/pic.jpg` (not the dot) or simply `res/pic.jpg`, or use the absolute path `/usr/share/myapp/res/pic.jpg`.